# Rotate geometry around its local axis

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

I tried to rotate a geometry around its local axis, but haven't found a way to do so. I know that there is `ST_Rotate` (see https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Rotate.html) for 2D calculations and (among others) `ST_RotateX` (see https://postgis.net/docs/ST_RotateX.html), but these methods rotate a geometry around the origin. I also tried to abuse `ST_Affine` when I tried to change (what seems to be) the origin (namely 0/0/0):

```
SELECT ST_Affine(
        ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(runway_area)),
        1, 0, 0, 0,
        cos(rotRadians), -sin(rotRadians), 0, sin(rotRadians), cos(rotRadians),
        --- use the geometry's centroid instead of 0, 0, 0
        ST_X(ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(runway_area))), ST_Y(ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(runway_area))), ST_Z(ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(runway_area)))
    )
```

It didn't work out - all I got was something that was way away from the intended location. Do I miss a very fundamental method by PostGIS here to rotate a geometry around one of its local axis?

Comment: How do you define "local axis", i.e., "local" to your set of geometries of interest, or the grid (SRS) axis? If former, how would you determine the centre of your set of geometries of interest?

Answer (score 2):

Take a closer look at [ST_Rotate](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Rotate.html), and note that there are three argument signatures:

> `geometry ST_Rotate(geometry geomA, float rotRadians);`
>   `geometry ST_Rotate(geometry geomA, float rotRadians, float x0, float y0);`
>   `geometry ST_Rotate(geometry geomA, float rotRadians, geometry pointOrigin);`

The `x0` and `y0` or `pointOrigin` arguments for the last two signatures do what your questions asks: they allow the rotation to pivot around a custom defined coordinate.

And an example from the docs show how to rotate a geometry 60 degrees clockwise around the centroid:

```
SELECT ST_AsEWKT(ST_Rotate(geom, radians(-60.0), ST_Centroid(geom)))
FROM (SELECT 'LINESTRING (50 160, 50 50, 100 50)'::geometry AS geom) AS foo;
                           st_asewkt
--------------------------------------------------------------
 LINESTRING(116.4225 130.6721,21.1597 75.6721,46.1597 32.3708)
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could combine `ST_Rotate` with `ST_Centroid`, example:

```
ST_Rotate(ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(runway_area)), -pi()/3, ST_Centroid(ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(runway_area)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The last three arguments to [`ST_Affine`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Affine.html) do not represent the origin, but the global "shift" in the affine transformation. The documentation for [`ST_RotateX`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_RotateX.html) shows how to use this function to generate a rotation around the x-axis. All these parameters are zero since it's a rotation without  translation.

If you want to employ a general axis, you would need to construct the corresponding [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle) and substitute its elements for the arguments `a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i` of `ST_Affine` and set `xoff, yoff, zoff` to zero.